# Display dynamic content depending of selected option in dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, frontend, forms

I'm developing an extension with a front controller that displays a dropdown with a list of countries. The idea is that when you select a country from the dropdown, the page will display a list of distributors in that country.

EDIT: the code below is almost complete and is fully working. The form posts successfully and everything, I just need help with the filtering of the distributors for each country. I'm just missing a small snippet of code, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The code that I have in my .phtml file is:

```
    <div class="page-title">
    <h1>distributors by country</h1>
</div>
<div class="std">

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid12-2">

                <?php
                //list from the extension with country names
                $mapcountries =   Mage::getModel('gmapstrlocator/gmapstrlocator')->getCollection();
                $mapcountriesArray = array();
                foreach ($mapcountries as $mapcountry) {
                    $mapcountriesArray[] = $mapcountry->getData('country');
                }

                //list from Magento with country names instead of iso codes
                $magecountries = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
                $magecountriesArray = array();
                foreach ($magecountries as $country) {
                    $magecountriesArray[] = $country->getName();
                }

                //display the intersection between both
                $finalcountries = array_intersect($magecountriesArray, $mapcountriesArray);
                sort($finalcountries, SORT_STRING);

                //add blank option to array
                $defaultValue = "Please select your country";

                //list of distributors from the extension
                $distributors = Mage::getModel('gmapstrlocator/gmapstrlocator')->getCollection();
                $distributorsArray = array();
                foreach ($distributors as $distro) {
                    $distributorsArray[] = $distro->getData('country');
                }
            ?>

            <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('distro/selected'); ?>" method="post">
                <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

                    <?php
                    //create dropdown with the array_intersect of countries in alphabetical order
                    $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
                    ->setName('countrylist')
                    ->setTitle('distributors by country')
                    ->setId('countrylist')
                    ->setClass('countrylist')
                    ->setOptions($finalcountries)
                    ->setValue($defaultValue);
                    echo $select->getHtml()
                    ?>

                        <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="countryform" id="countryform"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('submit') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['countryform'])) {
                        $countries = $_POST['countrylist'];
                    }
                ?>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="grid12-10">
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['countrylist'])) {
                //this is the part where I want to display the distributors that belong to each country
                echo "I work";
            }
            else {
                echo "Please select your country from the list to find our distributors by country";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone give me a hand with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't fetch data in template file, but if you want to do it, you could do it that way:

```
if(isset($_POST['countrylist'])) {
    $distributors = Mage::getModel('gmapstrlocator/gmapstrlocator')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('country_name', $_POST['countrylist']);
    $distributorsArray = array();
    foreach ($distributors as $distro) {
        $distributorsArray[] = $distro->getData('country');
    }
}
```

Change 'country_name' to name of column from distributors table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sebastian, do you recommend me to create a helper? I thought of doing it on the template file because it's where the form is, but I'm always open to better ideas.

Comment: You could create getDistributors($country_id) function in block, and then call it in template.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I've tried your code and works brilliantly. Is there any way I could retrieve more than one field from the database at once when calling $distributorsArray[] = $distro->getData('country'); ? Ideally, I'd like to retrieve address and phone number too.

Comment: $tmp['country'] = $distro->getData('country'); $tmp['address'] = $distro->getData('address'); $tmp['phone_number'] = $distro->getData('phone_number'); $distributorsArray[] = $tmp;

Comment: Where shall I place those variables: inside or outside the foreach? If I place them inside and echo $tmp, I get the error: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: You should place it inside foreach. You are creating temporary array and assign it to distributorsArray. If you want to see what is in $tmp, try this: print_r($tmp);

Comment: Sorted. Thanks a lot Sebastian, you've saved my day.